# How to match specific characters in String n-m times

Tags: java, regex, string

I intends to use REGEX in Java to match a String. For e.g.I have letters `'A' 'A' 'A' 'P' 'P' 'L' 'E' 'S'`.

I want to check whether a string contains `0-3 'A', 0-2 'P', 0-1 'L', 0-1 'E' and 0-1 'S'`.

Examples of string which shall pass the check:
`APPLE, APPLES, ALE, PALE... etc`

This is what I've tried:

```
if (str.matches("[A]{0,3}[P]{0,3}[L]{0,1}[E]{0,1}[S]{0,1}"))
```

**APPLES** successfully passed through the check but not **SAPPLE**.

Answer (score 3):

```
(?!(.*A){4,})(?!(.*P){3,})(?!(.*L){2,})(?!(.*E){2,})(?!(.*S){2,})^[APLES]*$
```

Try this.This will work for you.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sH6aF3/2

It uses a negative lookahead to ensure

`A` should not come 4 or more times.Similarly rest of the lookahead's ensure other conditions.In the end when its time to consume the string only selected characters inside `[]` are allowed.

Comment: What the I don't even... but you're right, it is correct. The OP would probably be helped if you added an explanation of how it works. +1 for answering the question, but a regexp is probably still the wrong way to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

Optimised version of [vks's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25946024/3622940):

```
^(?!(?>[^A]*A){4})(?!(?>[^P]*P){3})(?!(?>[^L]*L){2})(?!(?>[^E]*E){2})(?!(?>[^S]*S){2})[APLES]*$
```

Changes:

- Moved `^` anchor to the front.
- Changed capturing groups to atomic groups to prevent backtracking  - Possible drastic performance improvement when the string fails to match.
- Use `[^A]*A` et cetera in groups in place of `.*` backtracking to roll over the match efficiently.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/sH6aF3/3).

Comment: there's still a lot of learning left 4 me :)

Comment: that is so cool :) thanx. will go through them

Comment: How could I've overseen this riddle which looks so familiar :] Yours indeed seems to be more efficient when it comes to counting steps, whereas @vks' is a bit more compact and [mine](http://regex101.com/r/iR2hI2/1) would again be something in between regarding efficiency. Well didn't test that much.

Answer (score 1):

You are imposing a specific order to your letters (A before P before L before E before Q, that's why `APPLES` passes and not `SAPPLE`). Actually, I'm not sure what you want to do is even possible with a reasonably short regex. I would to it manually with a single loop and a Map to count the occurrences.

Comment: Do you know how to remove the specific order in my codes? I can use the conventional way of using a loop, but I think it might not be very efficient since I have possibly over 50,000 words from a dictionary to check.

Comment: Unless your code is running on a washing machine, 50k words is peanuts. And how do you think regexes are matched, if not with a loop?